# How to fix warning about incompatible pointer types?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm getting this warning:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableArray *__strong' with an expression of type 'NSArray *
```

This is the line of code giving the warning:

```
    NSMutableArray *apptDataArray = [AppointmentInfo MR_findAllWithPredicate:nsp];
```

where MR_findAllWithPredicate returns a NSArray.  I have been reading all of the postings in SO and Google, but found nothing like this.  I think it's fairly simple, but I need help.

Comment: Don't assign the address of an NSArray to a pointer that's typed NSMutableArray.  It's that simple.  (You *can* assign an NSMutableArray address to an NSArray pointer, however, since NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSArray` is *not* an `NSMutableArray`, thus the pointers are incompatible and calling mutating methods on it will crash. You can go the other way as an `NSMutableArray` *is* an `NSArray` subclass.

You can make an `NSMutableArray` from the return value with `+[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:]`:

```
NSMutableArray *apptDataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[AppointmentInfo MR_findAllWithPredicate:nsp]];
```

If your method ever returns `nil`, create an `NSArray *` variable and check for `nil` before creating the mutable array.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to BergQuester's answer, heres a shorter way to get a mutable array from an array:

```
NSMutableArray *apptDataArray = [[AppointmentInfo MR_findAllWithPredicate:nsp] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Just be sure to release the mutable array if you use copy and are not using ARC.